# Prove that square of cubes is smaller than or equal to cube of squares.

Tags: inequality, summation, real-numbers

I have to prove this ($a_i \in \mathbb{R}$):
$$(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}^3)^2 \leq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}^2)^3$$

I have tried using various known inequalities e.g. Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I didn't get any meaningful results. Could anybody show some interesting observations or tips to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: induction maybe ?

Comment: You might use $(a^3+b^3)^2 +a^2b^2(2a^2+(a-b)^2 +2b^2)=(a^2+b^2)^3$

Comment: @Surb Could you tell a bit more about an induction step? I have tried expanding it (with the formula for cube and square of sum) but I have no idea where to go after that.

Comment: Use @Henry's formula in the induction step.